# Simple Counter in JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple counter that allows the user to input a number and press a button which will then minus their number from 100 until the counter gets to 0. this is the HTML and JavaScript code:

HTML:

```
 <div class="box">    
            <label for="qty"><abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr></label>
            <input id="qty" type="number" max="100" />
            <button id="down" onclick="modify_qty(-qty)">Book</button>

        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 function modify_qty(val) {
        var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
        var new_qty = parseInt(qty,10) + val;

        if (new_qty == -1) {
            new_qty = 0;
            alert("Sorry Tickets Have Now Sold Out");
        }  
        document.getElementById('qty').value = new_qty;
        return new_qty;
    }
```

The problem is when the user inputs a number and presses the button, the number disappears. For example: the max is 100, if I enter 10, it should return 90. But it is returning nothing at all.

Comment: and what is the actual problem with the above code..?

Comment: sorry, the problem is when the user inputs a number and presses the button, the number disappears. For example, the max is 100. if i enter 10, it should return 90. but it is returning nothing at all

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9z0e3nfz/) what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9z0e3nfz/1/)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added another label to track the remaining tickets instead of putting the amount left in the input.

Using a `ticketsLeft` variable in the javascript helps to keep track of tickets without relying on our html to hold values for us.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfx3ow62/1/)

**Javascript**

```
var ticketsLeft = 100; 
var qty = document.getElementById('qty');
var remaining = document.getElementById('remaining');

remaining.innerHTML = ticketsLeft;

function modify_qty() {
        var new_qty = ticketsLeft - parseInt(qty.value, 10);
        if (new_qty < 0) {
            ticketsLeft = 0;
            remaining.innerHTML = 0;
            alert("Sorry Tickets Have Now Sold Out");
            return;
        }  
        ticketsLeft = new_qty;
        remaining.innerHTML = new_qty;
        return new_qty;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">    
    <label for="qty"><abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr></label>
    <input id="qty" type="number" max="100" />
    <button id="down" onclick="modify_qty()">Book</button>
    <label>Tickets Remaining: <label id="remaining"></label></label>
</div>
```